# Why Spring InternalResourceView doesn't throw an exception about not existing JSP file?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, requestdispatcher

Is it intended that Spring MVC doesn't throw `ServletException` when the expected JSP doesn't exist?
Code snippet below is the part of `InternalResourceView`, where an exception should be made in my opinion. `RequestDispatcher` might be null because there's no file on dispatcherPath.
In detail, dispatcherPath looks like `/WEB-INF/jsp/v2/post/somename.jsp`.

```html
  // Obtain a RequestDispatcher for the target resource (typically a JSP).
  RequestDispatcher rd = getRequestDispatcher(requestToExpose, dispatcherPath);
  if (rd == null) {
 throw new ServletException(
      "Could not get RequestDispatcher for [" + getUrl() +
      "]: Check that the corresponding file exists within your web application archive!");
  }
```

Comment: Yes it is, and it is historical. `InternalResourceView` is a `UrlBasedViewResolver` and basically all it does is construct a URL to somewhere. Which might or might not exist. If you want you could provide your own subclass of `JstlView` and implement the `checkResource` method to check if it actually exists. Then configure the `InternalResourceViewResolver` with this view.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for explanation. But I don't think `JstlView.checkResource` is an appropriate point to check whether jsp exists. 1. checkResource only has Locale parameter 2. ViewResolver might be able to check the existence beforehand. `UrlBasedViewResolver.buildView`, for example.

Comment: It is delegated to the `checkResource`  as that knows about the view technology. The view resolver (at least this one) doesn't know about the technology. Next to that the `View` extends `WebApplicationObjectSupport` which has a `ServletContext` so you can perfectly well check it in your `View`.

Comment: @M.Deinum fully understand what you meant. Thanks alot!